# Hide fields on sharepoint custom list form, No code

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have created a custom list with 3 below columns.

Name(Single line of text)
Approved(Radio Yes/No)
Comments(Multiple line of text)

I have changed the default forms and on Create new item form, i am displaying Name and Approve fields, here users create a new item using this form. Now on Edit Item form I want to display comments field only when the value in field Approved is No. I've heard that there is some xsl way, please let me know if you have any idea on this or any other way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use sharepoint manager.Foreach column there is a Show in edit form. Set this to false for all fields apart from your comments field. However be sure you don't hide a required field!!

Hope this helps

Cheers
   Truez